# Electron stop scripts from uploading/sending data

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, electron

Is it possible to use electron (and/or normal browsers) to prevent javascript files from capturing the DOM and sending it to a server by using Electron?  If so how?

Current solution (although I don't know how to implement them):

Restrict on the amount of uploaded data per JS file requested by the page

I'm open to suggestions on the best way to do it.

NOTE: I absolutely have to use this file - but I'm very concerned about the security side of things.

Comment: I am a little confused what you try to archive, since the only way to do this is by disabling javascript all together or preventing the connection the the internet (For example via a protocol filter trough electron).

Comment: @HanKoch thanks for the comment, but is there no way to prevent uploading but allowing downloading from scripts? ultimately thats what I want. I have JS files (this includes services such as Google Maps) which required remote data.

Comment: Not in the way you want to do it. You can however try to parse the http https etc. requests via https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md